# How the addon of the firefox is accessing the file sytem

Tags: javascript

firefox wont allow the javascript to save a file in client machine is the browser security policy

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1046

the above linked addon can save a file then why cant we save a file in the filesystem using javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code that is part of an extension the user explicitly chose to install is trusted more than code running on a page the user happens to visit. Thus, Firefox allows extension code this functionality (accessing the filesystem), but does not allow code running in a webpage to do this.

This makes sense: it's much easier for an attacker to get a user to accidentally visit his malicious page and run it's javascript (with invisible iframes, for example), than it is for an attacker to get the user to install a malicious extension. Additionally, Mozilla code reviews every extension on their website to make sure they aren't malicious.

I should also note that extensions don't have to be written in Javascript. Many of them are written in native code (C++ usually), and there are XPCOM (one of the ways extensions interface with the browser) bindings for other languages as well (Python, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is executed from the webpages you visit ; and, generally speaking, you cannot trust each and every webpage you visit -- which is why there are such security measures.

For the extensions, on the other hand :

- **You** decide which extension has the right to run on your system, as you are the one installing them

  - And installing an extension means you trust it.
- Are tested / reviewed by the team of AMO *(correct me if I'm wrong ?)*

Comment: They say the AMO team reviews them, I wouldn't expect much in the way of *testing* beyond a casual, cursory use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Submitting_an_add-on_to_AMO What they're "reviewing" them for is, of course, spying features and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Add-ons aren't subject to the security restrictions, because the user explicitly installed them (e.g., indicated trust). See the [extensions documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions) for details. This is very different from JavaScript running on a web page, which the user hasn't indicated they trust.